# In Adobe Audition, I saved/exported a 3h mix at +3dB. Have I lost tons of transients and dynamics?

Tags: music, adobe-audition, loudness, clipping

Is there any way to get it to sound just as loud on SoundCloud without losing quality? The clipping is there, I believe but it’s not very audible but becomes significant upon closer listening. I have saved files that preserve the signal and are under 0dB.

Comment: What's in your mastering chain? Are you just letting it hard-clip at 0dBFS? Anything above 0dB will simply not be saved in your output file, which you really don't want to do. Can you add some detail of your process to your question. [Most streaming services will auto-level your soundtrack, but Soundcloud isn't one of them, so you need to get it right before upload.]

Comment: I recorded straight from Stereo Mix to Audition. I amplified the waveform to an average peak of about 3dB. The final output file sounds nice and loud but I’m afraid I lose a really powerful low-end as a result as well as some dynamics and transients. I’ve done a lot of reading on the subject but I’m more curious as to what happens when you save a file like this. Is the clipping “inaudible” in that the recording isn’t destroyed but you just lose a lot of information?

Comment: Ramping the peaks to +3dBFS, I'm surprised you can't hear it crunching already, unless you have something in the chain that's soft-clipping the peaks. Audition might be smart enough to do that for you. I've never used it, so idk for sure. You ought to investigate 'mastering' plugins [there are hundreds] & look for something that will let you set your output for the streaming services, these days measured in LUFS [doesn't matter what it means or how it works, you have to get your files to conform to -14dBFS on a LUFS meter, or the services will just slam a volume reduction on your material.]